# Is there a way to take in a CSV and create fields or columns to table more quickly?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm dealing with a jxml file with a table in there. Now I want to insert more columns and attributes to that table. However, insert a column one by one by manual is so troublesome and cumbersome. Is there a way to take in a CSV file with the names of attributes and bulk insert columns or create fields?

Comment: Did you try to select several fields and use drag & drop?

Comment: yes, it's not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write a code to modify the table. Because the .jrxml file is the .xml file, which means I can modify it.